# status=1&enc_response=command is mandatory. while integrating CCAvenue

Tags: integration, payment, ccavenue

I trying to hit CCAvenue payment gateway, I am doing that with PostMan. I am having valid access_code, Working key and merchaint Id, but when I trying I am getting error like status=1&enc_response=command is mandatory. Can anyone help me out with this

Answer (score 4):

You content type in header should be `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `Content-Type: application/json`

FOR POSTMAN:
BODY should be `x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `form-data`.

**Find**

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,'Content-Type: application/json');
```

**Replace  with::**

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
```

TRY THIS KUDOS!

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel 10.x** using HTTP Client [Ref. link](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-client#sending-form-url-encoded-requests)

```
$merchant_json_data = array(
   'order_no' => '', //your app's internal order no
   'reference_no' => '' //ccavenue tracking no
);

$merchant_data = json_encode($merchant_json_data);
$encrypted_data = encrypt($merchant_data, $working_key);

$response = Http::asForm()->post('https://apitest.ccavenue.com/apis/servlet/DoWebTrans', [
   'enc_request' => $encrypted_data,
   'access_code' => $access_code,
   'command' => 'orderStatusTracker',
   'request_type' => 'JSON',
   'response_type' => 'JSON',
   'version' => '1.2'
])->body();

dd($response);
```